# setTimeout and e.preventDefault

Tags: jquery, ajax, preventdefault, quick-search, onpaste

I have two events listening on a unique field: autocomplete and onPaste.
My goal is to call another logic on paste, and use the autocomplete on typing.

I did this in the following way:

```
$("#refno").on('paste', function (e) { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        //some logic here
    }, 0);
    e.preventDefault();
})

function quickSearch(fieldName) {
    //some other logic here
} 

quickSearch('.open-invoices-quick-search');
```

The problem is that the e.preventDefault(); is called or too early (preventing the code from the setTimeout), or too late, allowing the quickSearch function to be executed.

Any idea how to deal with this situation?

Here is the JSFddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk242zkz/1/

Not possible to test as I can't find the autocomplete library.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: The `preventDefault()` is not stopping the `setTimeout()` call. The logic must have an issue caused by something else.

Comment: Why the 0 timeout? Won't be better just to execute your logic inside the event listener and prevent the event bubbling with event.cancelBubble = true; ?

Comment: @Bardo, [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: What is doing your quicksearch() method? Any async request? You have to provide more context regarding your question and share minimal of your 'logic' behind it

Comment: Create a simple demo that replicates the event timing issue. Not clear at all what your problem is

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I shared the JSFiddle link. thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff, the quicksarch method is using autocomplete and does an ajax call, the same as onPaste function.

Comment: @Miloš So what you want is done something once the autocomplete ajax request has completed? Is it?

Comment: @A.Wolff, no. My goal is to skip the autocomplete if the user does a paste. If paste, one action, if typing, another action (autocomplete).

Comment: Probably need to modify whatever autocomplete plugin you are using

Comment: @charlietfl, I am using the JQuery autocomplete plugin. I do not think it is a good idea to modify the plugin itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this logic instead, but style vague imho what is your expected behaviour...

```
$("#refno").on('paste', function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("disable").one('keydown', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("enable");
    });    
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

JqueryUI autocomplete provides some stock methods that you can call on the autocomplete element during and after initialization.

I'm sure you've seen it already but check out the API docs here for autocomplete:
[Autocomplete Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Inside of your paste event try using the disable method on your autocomplete object.
Don't forget to re-enable it after.